# Discard dataset iterators when saving model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to save my model using the following instruction:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='Vgg16'))  # Init saver
```

My model is a VGG16 CNN network which layers are organised under the Vgg16 scope:
[image]

Problem is that after recovering the model I still can see the DataPipe module (between others). What I am doing wrong?
These is the code I use to recover the trained model:

```
checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)
```

Any idea?